# Parse huge xml file to get distinct values from child tags -- need best approach suggestions

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax

I have an xml of the given form.

```
 <myData>
    <myElement>
            <myGroupID>ID1</myGroupID>
            <myGroupValue>value1</myGroupValue>
    </myElement>
    <myElement>
            <myGroupID>ID2</myGroupID>
            <myGroupValue>value2</myGroupValue>
    </myElement>
    <myElement>
            <myGroupID>ID3</myGroupID>
            <myGroupValue>value3</myGroupValue>
    </myElement>
        <myElement>
            <myGroupID>ID4</myGroupID>
            <myGroupValue>value4</myGroupValue>
    </myElement>
        <myElement>
            <myGroupID>ID1</myGroupID>
            <myGroupValue>value1</myGroupValue>
    </myElement>
    <myElement>
            <myGroupID>ID2</myGroupID>
            <myGroupValue>value2</myGroupValue>
    </myElement>
    <myElement>
            <myGroupID>ID3</myGroupID>
            <myGroupValue>value3</myGroupValue>
    </myElement>
        <myElement>
            <myGroupID>ID4</myGroupID>
            <myGroupValue>value4</myGroupValue>
    </myElement>
<myData>
```

The total number of `myElement` tags in the file can be 2-4million, and there are other tags in each of the elements.
As can be seen, the `myGroupID` and `myGroupValue` tags have duplicate values for different elements.

My requirement is to get distinct values of `myGroupID` and `myGroupValue` tags.

I was trying to use `Stax parser with Iterator api [event based approach]`. What I have learnt is, I'll have to go through all the tags to check if the `event.getLocalName` is `myGroupID` or `myGroupValue` and if so, then I'll have to use my logic of checking if the already parsed part of the file has any value as that of the current element.

But with this approach, I'm unnecessarily iterating through other tags [other than `myGroupID` and `myGroupValue` ], which is a waste of time as it seems.

Any idea how we can directly jump to tags with specific names within an element?

Not to mention that I had 0 or even less knowledge on stax parsing and just had the chance to learn it today, and I am to use java for this parsing.

Thanks in advance for our kind suggestions.

**Update:**

Thanks everyone for your valuable inputs. As off now, I'm using Stax Iterator API for addressing the requirement and it seems to be working pretty fast. Moreover, the memory used by the code is also acceptable `~3mb`, whereas the total size of the file I'm parsing is of `55mb`. Thus its going all good for me.

Just a few things that's still bothering me:- the XML is containing `leading` and `training` spaces and the `'-' character`. Any suggestions how we can get rid of them when we're not parsing a file, but directly parsing the XML coming from an input stream of an `HTTPConnection`?

I do not have the choice of getting a better XML here [without the `leading` and `trailing spaces` and the `'-' character`], as the XML I'm receiving is actually the response of a service from another system and they are not ready to modify their code to address our system's requirements.

Comment: Your first, best option would be to stop storing basically a whole couple of databases' worth of data in an XML file.  :P  That's not what XML was for, and you're now reaping the consequences of this design decision.

Comment: Try using vtd xml parser, but cHao is right in his comment.

Comment: @cHao The XML is basically a response that we've been receiving from a service of another system. Thanks for your suggestion though. I could not agree more with you :P

Answer (score 0):

Why not use SAX?
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

```
public void startElement(....) {
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("myElement")) {
        //do stuff, inElement = true, prepare new element...
    }

    else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("MYGROUPID") && inElement) {
        //do stuff
    }

    else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("MYGROUPVALUE") && inElement) {
        //do stuff
    }
```

Analogical, in endElement(), when "myElement" closing brace is found, you should switch inElement to false and store or do anything else with groupId and groupValue taken from current element. This is best way to go, and pretty fast - even faster than Stax, with still minimal memory req.

Comment: SAX is actually heavier weight and slower than StAX.  Part of this is due not StAX being able to avoid converting unused data to `String` where as SAX always has to do this processing.

Comment: It may depend on your choice of parser and the design of your application, but I have seen no significant difference in speed between SAX and StAX. SAX is fact is very carefully designed to avoid unnecessary moving of character data into strings.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable inputs. As off now, I'm using Stax Iterator API for addressing the requirement and it seems to be working pretty fast. Moreover, the memory used by the code is also acceptable `~3mb`, whereas the total size of the file I'm parsing is of `55mb`. Thus its going all good for me.

Comment: Just a few things that's still bothering me:- the XML is containing `leading` and `training spaces` and the `'-' character`. Any suggestions how we can get rid of them when we're not parsing a file, but directly parsing the XML coming from an input stream of an `HTTPConnection`?

Comment: I do not have the choice of getting a better XML here [without the `leading` and `trailing spaces` and the `'-' character`], as the XML I'm receiving is actually the response of a service from another system and they are not ready to modify their code to address our system's requirements.

Comment: @aritra: What it will take you to code in 100 lines in SAX, you will do it with 10 lines in vtd-xml, and vtd-xml gives you far better performance every time...

Comment: @vtd-xml-author- Hi, I do not have any knowledge on `vtd-XML`. Incase, if you have got any documentation on `vtd-xml` you can mail it to me on my id `aritrab@hotmail.com`. I will definitely go through it and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @aritra - whitespaces are ignored (except elements values ofcourse), so xml don't have to be pretty-printed or one-lined. But how about '-' character? Is it placed outer of xml mark? If xml is valid with w3c standard, you don't have to worry.